# Netbeans shows UNUSUAL errors BY Project from Existing Source

Tags: zend-framework, netbeans, netbeans-7.4

I m using Netbeans 7.4, After I created a social engine zend project from EXISTING SOURCES, Netbeans shows many unusual n unexpected errors. The project is clean & error-free. Despite the fact that Netbeans cant treat that as ZEND project automatically, it shows errors (parse/syntax error etc).The project also runs clean. Pls help 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same issue, to solve this I went into each file and checked what it was complaining about.

After opening one of the files with a reported error, you can click on the red line in the right hand margin to jump to the error line, and mouse over the line to get the error description.

You might need to tweak the settings in "Tools > Options > Editor > Hints"

Comment: but dont u think tweaking this way may mess the other new projects.This is just the solution to symptom, not the real problem.I also noticed that there are problems/errors that even doesnt have any tool>option>editor>hint. any other way around of this ?

Comment: I agree I would rather not tweak the settings, but sometimes you need to to fit in with company/community standards.  Can you upload the file somewhere so I can have a look? gist on github/pastebin?

Comment: Man its SOCIALENGINE FRESH installation, it even shows NO ERROR with Netbeans 7.2.I guarantee there is no error.Socialengine is reputed to be very error prone,a single error wont allow u to run in"develmnt mode" And the errors are soooo many and UN-tracable,weird dat u'll get fed-up.Thnx by d way for the reply

Comment: That is frustrating :/ I also see that you have to pay for it before you can download :/ Like I said in answer, just check each file and see what netbeans thinks the error is, I'm sure it's something small...

Comment: Lol...the ERROR is Netbeans ITSELF, like I said, the same project doesnt show errors in Netbeans 7.2. The project's been running well WITH these errors.I just had to close my eyes to these "RED" unbearable error signs...sigh!!